# Setting User Profile Picture, Logon Background WinApi/C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I was wondering how to change the User Picture of the current user (Function, NetSetUserInfo or Registry) and the Logon Background (also Function,NetSetUserInfo or Registry). I couldn't find anything on this topic.
All help is appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66273110/how-to-set-accounts-picture-in-windows-10

Comment: @Halfix Alright thanks for that, the logon image baсkground remains.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1126403/what-is-the-location-of-lock-screen-images-on-windows-10

Comment: To change the logon image baсkground, you could refer to the sample: [Lock screen personalization sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/personalization/)